# Alphabetically sort table view

Tags: xcode, uitableview, core-data, alphabetized

How can I programme a table view to alphabetically sort new data that is added? I have found examples however these only show how to sort arrays of data. The data added is from an attribute string using core data. Is there a way of sorting new data alphabetically?

Comment: Don't think of it as sorting the TableView, think of it as sorting the data and then reloading the TableView. It'll end up looking like the same thing, but it'll make it easier to research and find solutions.  I haven't used CoreData, so I'm not quite sure, but I do know that you won't end up sorting the TableView itself.

Comment: If you use Core Data, you can also use `NSFetchedResultsController`. It will handle data addition and re-sorting if you implement its delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

edited with suggestions from @Andrei Filip 
you want to look at the NSSortDescriptor class

you then have to create an array of sortDescriptors even if its only one

Then call sortedArrayUsingDescriptors on your array passing in the sortDescriptors array

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:<#what attribute you want to sort on#> ascending:YES];


NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];


<#your array to sort#> = [<#your array to sort #> sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

This will sort the array alphabetically. The just call reloadData on the tableView

Comment: So would my array name be the attribute name  from my data?

Comment: The attribute name should replace <#what you want to sort on#>
Also replace "sortedArray" with your array's name